# Problema em algoritmo de pilha em C (Struct e a função não se "reconhecem")

Tags: c, ponteiro, struct, estrutura-de-dados

Olá, Estou iniciando no estudo de estruturas de dados e um dos algoritmos passados é para incremento de dados num vetor como numa pilha (ou seja, o ultimo incrementado é o primeiro à sair) estou na parte da incrementação e estou tendo problemas com relação a atuação do meu ponteiro na hora de apontar os atributos da minha struct pilha. Já tentei fazer isso sem que nessesáriamente p fosse um ponteiro, pois assim o código parece "reconhecer" os atributos, mas não tem dado certo. Por enquanto o código está assim.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define stack_length 100

struct stack {

int top;
int itens[stack_length];
};
void push(struct stack *p, int e ){
if (p.top == (stack_length - 1)){
    printf ("\nestouro de pilha");
    exit(1);
}
    p.itens[++(p.top)] = e;
    printf("%d",e);

void main (){
int e = 6;

}
```

Quanto aos erros eles são: `Error request for member 'top' in something not a structure or a union`
`Error request for member 'itens' in something not a structure or a union`

Nas linhas 11 e 16, respectivamente:

Linha 11: `if (p.top == (stack_length - 1)){`
(...)

Linha 16: `p.itens[++(p.top)] = e;`

ps: Ainda não mexi propriamente na função main, preenchi ali só para desencargo de consciência...

Comment: Como p é um ponteiro para a estrutura use: `p->top` e `p->itens...` ou, se preferir utilizar a notação com  '.': `(*p).top`.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei qual compilador você esta usando mas no codeblocks quando trabalhamos com ponteiros 
se usa "->" em vez de ".", outra coisa quando vc esta modificando um ponteira ele deve estar entre parenteses e com asteriscos antes tipo: (*p)->item[++((*p)->top)]